# Not able to fetch updated content from div contenteditable on keyup event

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using `<div contenteditable>` to apply different styling to multiple lines.

Here, `assetSerialNumber` and `assetLocation` gets populated in `connectedcallback()` method in js.
I am using `divTextarea` in class to make `div` look like `textarea` which is working fine.

`.html file`

```
<div id="divcontenteditable" class="divTextarea slds-textarea" contenteditable onkeyup={handleChange}> 
   <p>Device request:  {assetSerialNumber}</p>
   <p>Device location {assetLocation}</p>
</div>
```

`.js file`

```
handleChange(event) {
        var input = this.template.querySelector(".divTextarea");
        console.log(input.innerText);
        console.log(input.textContent);
    }
```

**Scenario 1:** If I am typing any text to either of `<p>` tags under `<div contenteditable>`, `handleChange` method is able to retrieve updated text values.

**Scenario 2:** If I press `ENTER` and starts typing, **I am not able to get updated text**. Everytime `ENTER`is pressed, a new `<p>` is added under `<div contenteditable>` like below and `handleChange` method still returns the original text`

```
<div id="divcontenteditable" class="divTextarea slds-textarea" contenteditable onkeyup={handleChange}> 
       <p>Device request:  {assetSerialNumber}</p>
       <p>Device location {assetLocation}</p>
       <p>New text</p>
 </div>
```

How can I achieve scenario 2 i.e. to fetch updated content when text is added in a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get updated content from div with below approach. I removed default text from html file and added those in `innerHTML` in js file. Then I was able to get updated content from `input.textContent`.

`html file`

```
<div id="divcontenteditable" class="divTextarea slds-textarea" contenteditable 
onkeyup={handleChange} lwc:dom="manual"></div>
```

`js file`:

```
let divTextarea = this.template.querySelector('.divTextarea');
divTextarea.innerHTML = '<p>'+Device request:+' '+this.assetSerialNumber+'</p>'+'<p>'+Device location+' '+this.assetLocation+'</p>';
```

and then onkeyup event will handled like below:

```
handleChange(event) {
   var input = this.template.querySelector(".divTextarea");
   console.log(input.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are referencing reactive properties in the markup ({assetSerialNumber} and {assetLocation}), the framework will apply the value that those properties have (taken from the JavaScript file) when the component in rerendered. If you want to go down the contenteditable approach, you should do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div
    id="divcontenteditable"
    class="divTextarea slds-textarea"
    contenteditable
    onkeyup={handleChange}
  >
    <p>
      Device request: <span class="serial-number">{assetSerialNumber}</span>
    </p>
    <p>Device location: <span class="location">{assetLocation}</span></p>
  </div>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class EditableContent extends LightningElement {
  assetSerialNumber = "serialNumber";
  assetLocation = "location";

  handleChange(event) {
    var serialNumber = this.template.querySelector(".serial-number");
    var location = this.template.querySelector(".location");
    this.assetSerialNumber = serialNumber.textContent;
    this.assetLocation = location.textContent;
  }
}
```

Said that, this is not the best practice. What I'd do instead is to use lightning-inputs as follows:

```
<template>
  <lightning-input
    type="text"
    label="Device request:"
    value={assetSerialNumber}
    onchange={handleSerialNumberChange}
  >
  </lightning-input>

  <lightning-input
    type="text"
    label="Device location:"
    value={assetLocation}
    onchange={handleLocationChange}
  >
  </lightning-input>
</template>

import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class EditableContent2 extends LightningElement {
  assetSerialNumber;
  assetLocation;

  handleSerialNumberChange(event) {
    this.assetSerialNumber = event.detail.value;
    console.log(this.assetSerialNumber);
  }

  handleLocationChange(event) {
    this.assetLocation = event.detail.value;
    console.log(this.assetLocation);
  }
}
```

This way, you're delimiting the area in which the user needs to write, you're using the native mechanism of listening to an input event, and also you're following SLDS for a better UX. Also, you can take advantage of other capabilities that lightning-input has, as supporting different data types and validation.

Comment: I cannot use `lightning-input` since I need to show these values in one text box in multiple lines. And I cannot use `lightning-textarea` since I have to apply different styling to different lines. Hence, I have gone ahead with `contenteditable` approach. The problem I am facing is the "scenario 2" mentioned in the question i.e. when user starts interacting with the content in that `div`.

Comment: Then try the first solution I gave you, it works with contenteditable

Comment: I had tried `textContent` and it does give me updated text for `scenario 1`(also mentioned in question). However, as mentioned in scenario 2, When I press `ENTER`, it adds a new `<p>` tag and content of this new p tag is not displayed `textContent`. It only shows me the content of existing `<p>` tags.

Comment: Ok so then I misunderstood your question just by the fact that I didn’t see you assigning a value to the properties that you are referencing in the markup and that would result in the renderization of a property that contains nothing (so an empty space).

Comment: I think that this is happening to you because you are modifying the DOM manually and that's not allowed in LWC. LWC has a internal representation of the DOM (virtual DOM) and it get's out of sync with the real DOM (the contenteditable feature is allowing the manual modification). Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's correct. Is there a possible workaround to overcome this?

Comment: No as far as I know...